# GRUB background image overlays last image - can't clear old image

Tags: grub2

My **old** GRUB background image is overlaid by my **new** GRUB background image.

[image]

- Ubuntu 16.04
- GRUB 2

I set a GRUB background image:

- small **white** Ubuntu logo
- on **transparent** background

I then:

- edited my image to position the logo more centrally
- saved to a new filename under /boot/grub/
- moved the old file to my own user folders
- ran sudo update-grub

Now I see my **new** image nice and central, but the **old** image persists underneath the new one.

Any ideas or advice on how to clear it ?

Comment: I cant see any mistakes in the steps you used to set up the background-image in Grub, so it's probably the image itself. What do you see if you browse to /boot/grub and just double-click the image?

Comment: @mook765 Yep ... Doubting my own sanity, I did try the obvious and double triple check the image was good and displayed what I expected.

Comment: Some thinking this morning at work raised a theory which I will test at home this evening and report back. Perhaps the background image is compiled into a specific "memory range" in the boot code. When the image is changed **and has transparency** then the transparent elements of the image are not "reloaded into the memory range" - hence the superposed images. So what I will test is to create a flat single colour image of the same size, as JPG with **no transparency** and `update-grub` on that - then revert to my desired image, as PNG with transparency and `update-grub` again.

Comment: Probably a bug in Grub. Check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays) in which locations you could have background-images, normally Grub should choose only one even if more then one image is available in one ore in different locations. I would check all the locations, maybe you find something...Your last comment just arrived, listens like a good idea...

Comment: @mook765 : I checked thoroughly for older images lying around in locations where they would get picked up. _Totally cleaned up 100%_. When I run `update-grub` the output definitely finds only **one** image.

Comment: I did try the JPG **non-transparent** image theory last night to "flush out / overwrite" the persistent image remnants, but I didn't have the format reduced to 8-bit (256 colours) so it didn't load. I'll try again tonight.